# How can I tell what "Internal error" in Google Mail app

Tags: htc-desire, gmail, notifications

For a couple of days now I've had error messages when viewing my mail in the Google Mail app.
In the beginning the error was displayed when loading mails further down the list.

By now I won't see any mails at all first entry is "Internal error"

Since these issues started the notifications of new mails has stopped working as well and I could not open certain mails (with and without attachments)

How can I get to the bottom of this?

Thanks, seb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the database is corrupted.  I would go to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications` and clear the data for Gmail and Gmail Storage.  If that doesn't work, try clearing the data for everything Google (Talk, Google Framework Services, etc.).

Comment: I thought about doing that, thanks. Done and now I'm waiting for the mails to sync...

Comment: This is weird.  If you're using the wireless network, have you tried WiFi?  And vice-versa.  More than one WiFi network?  Have you tried logging in to your Gmail from the web?

Comment: Also note that Gmail 2.3.4 came out today, you may want update.

Comment: Hi, I did restart my phone and after that it was immediately available, email notifications as well!

Comment: Great, glad it's working :)

Answer (score 1):

Glad your problem is resolved. However, to answer the question a little more directly, there are logs where additional information for things such as this often exist. You can download [Android System Info](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi) from [ElectricSheep](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=ElectricSheep) and you can view the logs here. It's very unfriendly but is sometimes helpful.